# How to return Boolean from jQuery plugin to html?

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-plugins

I am currently working on a password strength meter that provides real-time update to the user via onkeyfocus event. I have decided to use https://github.com/elationbase/jquery.passwordRequirements for this purpose. Currently I am trying to return a Boolean from the jQuery plugin to my html so that I could check if the user input password has met the requirement completely. If it does not, to prevent them from further continuing in whatever they are doing. Below is what I have came up with so far. My question is how can I pass the var `is_passed` back to the html?

**jQuery Plugin**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        passwordRequirements: function(options) {
            // options for plugin
            var defaults {...};
            options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            var is_passed = false; // the variable that I wish to return

            return this.each(function() {
                ... //skipping all the checks
                $(this).on("keyup focus", function(){
                    var thisVal = $(this).val();
                    if (thisVal !== '') {
                        checkCompleted();
                        if (is_passed === true) {
                            console.log('is_passed', is_passed);
                            return is_passed;
                        }
                    } 
                )};
```

**HTML**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.pr-password').passwordRequirements({});
        var is_passed = $('.pr-password').passwordRequirements({}); //not working as it returns an Obj
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it using `callback`.

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        passwordRequirements: function(options, callback) {
            // options for plugin
            var defaults
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            var is_passed = false; // the variable that I wish to return

            return this.each(function() {
                //skipping all the checks
                $(this).on("keyup focus", function() {
                    var thisVal = $(this).val();
                    if (thisVal !== '') {
                        checkCompleted();
                        if (is_passed === true && callback !== null) {
                            return callback({
                                is_passed: is_passed
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.pr-password').passwordRequirements({}, function (action) {
            if (action.is_passed){
                passwordRequirement_passed = action.is_passed;
            }
        });
    });        
</script>
```